# Knowing about ones Code contribution to a particular Project/Solution in TFS

Tags: tfs

Is there a way to get know how much code you've written/modified/worked on via TFS?

It could be useful for one to know about how much lines of code they've been writing and get to know about statistics like defects per lines of code written etc. Could be useful to measure ones productivity also.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no such metric available in TFS today.

You can get some data using the code churn reporting that is available. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jampick/archive/2010/07/06/tfs-2010-code-churn-report-getting-additional-detail.aspx